# Java SSH2 libraries in depth: Trilead/Ganymed/Orion [/other?]

Tags: java, ssh

I have been searching for a pure Java SSH library to use for a project. The single most important needed feature is that it has to be able to work with command-line git, but remote-controlling command-line tools is also important.

A pretty common choice, e.g. used in the IntelliJ IDEA git integration (which works very well), seems to be Trilead SSH2. Looking at their website, it's not being maintained any more.

Trilead seems to have been a fork of Ganymed SSH2, which was a ETH Zurich project that didn't see releases for a while, but had a recent release by its new owner, Christian Plattner.

There is another actively maintained fork from that code base, Orion SSH, that saw an even more recent release, but which seems to get mentioned online much less than the other 2 forks.

Has anybody here worked with any of (or, if possible, both) of Ganymed and Orion and could kindly describe the development experience with either/both?

Accuracy of documentation [existence of documentation?], stability, buggyness... - all of these would be highly interesting to me. Performance is not so important for my current project.

If there is another pure-Java SSH implementation that should be used instead, please feel free to mention it, but please don't just mention a name...describe your judgment from actual experience.

Sorry if this question may seem a bit "do my homework"-y, but I've really searched for reviews. Everything out there seems to be either a listing of implementations or short "use this! it's great!" snippets.

Comment: Just out of interest, Bernd, which SSH library did you choose in the end?

Comment: I did go with Ganymed in the end, which was a good enough experience (although you can feel its age in the Java APIs and types it tends to use) for the basic stuff I got into, but I didn't get into really nice SSH work because the project was suspended for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the [Maverick](http://www.sshtools.co.uk/en/j2ssh-maverick/) project.

Comment: Commercial licensing + no pricing information *immediately* visible = No. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Ganymed is now actively maintained again with an open development process at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/).

Comment: At this time, there have been no changes in that repo for about two years; it appears to be abandoned.

Comment: No, it is not abandoned. Development is still active and artifacts are now also available in Maven Central.

Comment: Indeed -- at the end of July, development picked back up. Have there been efforts to keep in sync with the trilead ssh2 branch maintained and published by TMateSoft (or coordinate an attempted merger)?

Comment: As of this writing https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/list shows (nontrivial) changes as of May 2014.

Comment: In the meantime I no longer maintain Ganymed-SSH2 but have moved to https://github.com/dkocher/sshj

Answer (score 2):

[Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch) is another pure java ssh implementation. It's used by plenty of big projects, but I've heard the API is hard to use - I haven't used it personally.

I've used Ganymed-ssh for (rather simple but critical) task in production code with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've used ganymed, migrated to trilead, for several years. The basic functionality is quite stable, I would recommend it.

However, one issue to be aware of is that the threading model is very basic (thread per session). So it is very thread-hungry if you require many sessions at one time. That's really the only limitation we've run into.

The documentation is okay. There are enough examples to get yourself going in very little time.

Answer (score 1):

[TMateSoft](http://tmatesoft.com/) is actively maintaining Trilead SSH2 in [their Subversion repository](http://svn.svnkit.com/repos/3rdparty/com.trilead.ssh2/trunk), and publishing new releases to Maven (most recently, of this writing, adding SSH agent support in build 217).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [patched Trilead used in Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/trilead-ssh2), though changes are restricted to those directly applicable to this usage.